# Angular 5 Blocking iframe google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, iframe, xss

I have the following iframe

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  [src]="mapsurl" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

the `mapsurl` is a secured url (https)

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
>           at DomSanitizerImpl.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize

I checked a few resources. The angular docs are insufferable as is usual. I am continuing to research will edit question with findings. Any help is prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **DomSanitizer**

```
   import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

   constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
```

Then in the HTML:

```
    <iframe [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(mapsurl)'  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: awesome thank you. I saw this and was researching it and trying to implement. Really appreicate! but where do I import the domsanitizer app module?

Comment: Glad this could help you